# От полей инпут в хеш парамс идут пустые строки?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

К полям прикручены гемы simple_for, bootstrap3-datetimepicker-rails, bootstrap-sass. После submita поля start_date и end_date отправляют пустые значения в хеш params. В чем может быть проблема... кто знает? Спасибо[image: ![вьюха]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZMMjE.png)

Comment: вставляйте код как фрагмент кода, а не как картинку

Comment: Вставьте текст, не картинку. И приложите подробности: какие параметры в запросе всё-таки есть, например.

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо всем! Я просто не дописал в файл `config/initializers/date_time_picker_input.rb` несколько строк. Это чисто моя ошибка. Вот оригинал для работы bootstrap datetimepickera:

```
class DateTimePickerInput < SimpleForm::Inputs::Base

def input
  template.content_tag(:div, class: 'input-group date form_datetime') do
  template.concat @builder.text_field(attribute_name, input_html_options)
  template.concat span_table
    end
  end

  def input_html_options
    classes = (super[:class] || [])
    classes << :'form-control'
    options = super
    options.merge({class: classes})
    options.merge({readonly: false}) unless options[:readonly]
    options
  end
end
```